# Query executes with no error but not in trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, triggers

I am facing a strange problem in creating trigger in MS SQL.
I have a query that executes with out an error but when I place it within trigger body, it gives error

> Invalid column name 'ScreenName'.

I am placing whole trigger code here.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_tbFieldLabels_FieldLabelLength] ON [dbo].[tbFieldLabels]
AFTER INSERT
AS
    Update tbFieldLabels 
    Set TextBoxLength = (SELECT top 1 TextboxLength 
                              FROM  tbFieldLabelsSource FLS
                              WHERE FLS.ScreenName = Inserted.ScreenName
                              AND  FLS.SystemName = Inserted.SystemName)
     FROM tbFieldLabels , Inserted WHERE tbFieldLabels.ID = Inserted.ID
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error does not correlate to the trigger code shown.

Given this structure:

```
create table tbFieldLabels (id int, screenname varchar(10), systemname varchar(10), textboxlength int);
create table tbFieldLabelsSource (screenname varchar(10), systemname varchar(10), textboxlength int);
insert tbFieldLabelsSource select 'abc', 'def', 99;
insert tbFieldLabelsSource select 'zyx', 'def', 67;
GO
```

The following trigger can be created successfully:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_tbFieldLabels_FieldLabelLength] ON [dbo].[tbFieldLabels]
AFTER INSERT
AS
    Update tbFieldLabels 
    Set TextBoxLength = (SELECT top 1 TextboxLength 
                              FROM  tbFieldLabelsSource FLS
                              WHERE FLS.ScreenName = Inserted.ScreenName
                              AND  FLS.SystemName = Inserted.SystemName)
     FROM tbFieldLabels , Inserted WHERE tbFieldLabels.ID = Inserted.ID
GO
```

Your code in the question would have failed with

> The multi-part identifier "tbFieldLabelsSource.SystemName" could not be bound.

Because you have aliased `tbFieldLabelsSource` as `FLS`, but are still referencing it via the full name.

Using the trigger shown above, I can run this:

```
insert tbFieldLabels select 4, 'zyx', 'def', null;
```

Which is successful and inserts this record:

```
id          screenname systemname textboxlength
----------- ---------- ---------- -------------
4           zyx        def        67
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I am not facing this issue you mentioned. I have probably modified it forgot to use alias. In this case the same error appears that you mentioned. But I am facing the other problem. The database is denying the existence of columns that are in where clause.

Comment: The query within 'AS' and 'Go' is running fine but when i run whole trigger. I causes error 'Invalid column name 'ScreenName''

Comment: If you're not showing your exact code, nobody can help you. As for `query between AS and GO running fine` - this is IMPOSSIBLE because the INSERTED virtual table doesn't exist outside of a trigger. Edit your question with more facts.